# PushBot Push Notifications Xcode 4.6.3

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications

Has anyone been able to implement PushBot as a push notification service on an app? Their set up is relatively simple but I'm having issues..

Some of the errors I get when I build my app.
2013-08-05 10:18:18.490 TNPAppStore[421:907] Application ID not found in Pushbots.plist .
2013-08-05 10:18:18.506 TNPAppStore[421:907] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2013-08-05 10:18:18.805 TNPAppStore[421:907] Application ID not found in Pushbots.plist .
2013-08-05 10:18:18.806 TNPAppStore[421:907] Application ID not found in Pushbots.plist .
2013-08-05 10:18:19.262 TNPAppStore[421:907] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2013-08-05 10:18:19.630 TNPAppStore[421:907] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/1947CDB9-1684-4C88-A4BF-DEE9BE61557D/TNPAppStore.app/www/index.html

I've read throughout PushBots documentation but haven't really been able to find an answer why my Application ID isn't being read on my .plist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with PushBot's support we figured out that recreating the .plist from scratch and doing a clean the .plist was read correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I have same problem !! cleaning and recreating doesn't solve the it ! , iOS 8 , iPhone 6